# sort filename | uniq > output is not removing the duplicates

Tags: command-line

So I am using the command as follows:

```
sort file1.txt | uniq > cleared.txt
```

However, the cleared.txt file has exactly the same size and all the duplicates are still there. Could you please explain what is wrong in the way I am trying to do and maybe give alternatives also?

Thanks!

Update: I tried to use the following awk command but the duplicates are still there.

```
awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

Maybe it can be useful to mention that the file I am trying to clean is collected from different files that might be originating from different countries/layouts. **Please note that I want to keep one copy of the duplicated words.**

Comment: add the options `-iu` to `uniq` and lets see if it works

Comment: Hello @George , still have the duplicates. However, the size changed from 21.5 to 21.3 MB. I just updated the question

Comment: Can you provide the text that you're trying to sort ?  If so, use paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link to your paste here

Comment: Is the `sort` working as it should ? Check that its parsing the right information in the right order to `uniq`

Comment: @Serg I tried to copy/paste the whole document but when I click on paste of ctrl+c nothing happens in the browser. So, I copied a the last potion of the file and pasted it. Here is the link http://paste.ubuntu.com/23671296/

Comment: @George how can I check that? the words are already sorted in an alphabetical order and I get no errors

Comment: @Never.too.old.to.learn I looked at the file, tried it with `sort input.txt | uniq` , it works OK and gives only one word if there's two or more same words( I tested it by adding 3rd `zyklopischem` and result was only one word). Very hard to point out what's the issue in your case. What is your sort version ? Do `sort --version`

Comment: That's weird! This is my sort --version output:
[sort (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.]

Comment: Hmmm, version 8.25, same as mine . . .  Sorry, I don't know what could be the issue, because it works perfectly fine on my side. Maybe someone else will figure it out

Comment: @Serg Yeah I find this very weird too. As a temporary solution I used free online service for removing the duplicates and now everything is fine

Comment: @Never.too.old.to.learn  While I can't help to figure out the core of the issue, i can only provide an alternative solution for doing sort+uniq in python. `python -c "import sys;lines=sys.stdin.readlines();print ''.join(sorted(set(lines),key=str.lower))"  < duplicates.txt` Lengthy but works.

Comment: uniq works for me in Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 32-bit. Which version (e.g. 16.10) and architecture (e.g. 64-bit) are you running? Could you have an 'own' uniq, that is selected instead the one from coreutils? What is the output of 'uniq --version' (without quotes)?

Comment: As a side note why on earth do I need an UbuntuOne account to download that test data.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you have trailing spaces which are causing the non-unique designation.  Try stripping them out with xargs, like:

```
sort file1 | xargs -n 1 |uniq
```

Comment: -1 This is a terrible hack to strip trailing white-space. A much better alternative is `sed -re 's/\s+$//' file1.txt` or `grep -oe '^.*\S' file1.txt`.